# SessionFactory is null

Tags: spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

I'm using Spring with Hibernate and originally set up my project [with a hibernate xml config](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-xmlconfig), which resulted in performance issues and seemed like it was the wrong way to do it. I'm now trying to inject my SessionFactory, starting with 1 dao, but get a null pointer exception where sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() is called. I think my code looks like the examples I've seen. I'm stumped. I also tried not using resource and injecting the sessionFactory into the dao in the application context instead. Same result.

ApplicationContext.xml

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="path.to.base">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mappingDirectoryLocations">
       <list>
           <value>classpath*:/path/to/mapping/files</value>
       </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

myDAO

```
@Repository
public class myDAO {
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Resource(name="sessionFactory")
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public myDAO() {

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public List<Things> getAllThings() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(EvalMasterEvaluationType.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("active", "Y")).addOrder(Order.desc("createDtTm")).list();

}
```

}

Spring 3.2.1, Hibernate 3.6.10

Comment: Data source is not set properly

Comment: I had come across similiar issue. it was due to data source not set properly

Comment: I don't think that's it. I'm not missing any properties in my datasource and I know the driver, url, username and password are correct. I've tried different classes, but that didn't help. It may be something outside these files though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, though I'm not sure which modification solved the problem. SRT_KP might be right after all about the datasource since I added some properties to it (maxactive, maxidle, validationquery). I switched to LocalSessionFactoryBean since I'm using xml mappings and added the mapping file suffix to the mappingLocations property. I also moved @Transactional to the service layer where it belongs.

Here's what I ended up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:WEB-INF/*.properties"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.base.to.scan">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>



<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="oraDataSource" />
    <property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath*:org/path/to/mapping/files/*.hbm.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="oraDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 'x' FROM dual" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

BTW great tutorial: http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-with-hibernate-persistence-and-transactions-example